# Load text from specific div in text file using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the [jquery hovercard plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard) to pull in text from a text file using ajax when a user hovers over a particular text string - this all works great, (code below).

Now what I would like to do is have a number of different divs inside the text file, (shown below), and pull in the relevant one depending on which text string is hovered over. Is this possible with Jquery/Ajax, and if yes, how do you do it please?

*//Text File Contents*

```
<div id="John_Resig">
<div class="contact">John Resig</div>
<p><strong>Testing testing testing!</strong></p>
<p>And on another line of text : )</p>
</div>

<div id="Tim_Berners_Lee">
<div class="contact">Tim Berners-Lee</div>
<p><strong>Testing testing testing!</strong></p>
<p>And on another line of text : )</p>
</div>
```

*//Jquery/Ajax Code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var hoverHTMLDemoAjax = '<div class="demo-cb-tweets"></div>';
$(".demo-ajax").hovercard({
    detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
    width: 350,
    delay: 500,
    cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg',
    onHoverIn: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "text",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".demo-cb-tweets").prepend('<p class="loading-text">Loading latest tweets...</p>');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".demo-cb-tweets").empty();
                $(".demo-cb-tweets").html(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('.loading-text').remove();
            }
        });
    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: [JSON](http://www.json.org/) ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)) would be perfect for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your text files contains html markup, you can manipulate then using jQuery.

```
success: function (data) {
    var people = $(data),
        john = people.filter('#John_Resig');

    $(".demo-cb-tweets").empty().append(john);
}
```

Wrapping a string of html in a jQuery object turns it into a jQuery object that you can then use and insert into the dom, ie: `$('<div>Test</div>').addClass('test-class').appendTo('body');`

**EDIT:** Pulling out names:

You can pull out names from your text file in the same manner.  For example, on page load if you had an ajax call to the text file that would initialize all the times.  The following code would take your text file, and loop over each  container element (in your example, John_Resig and Tim_Berners_Lee):

```
success: function (data) {
    var people = $(data);

    people.each(function (i, person) {
        var name;
        if (person.nodeType !== 3) { // Your text file example had a blank line between the containing div elements... which loads as a nodeType of 3, so we'll want to skip those.
            name = $('.contact', person).text(); // This would grab the text inside of the div with the class 'contact'.
            // do stuff with that name here...

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks Alex; I tried your code but couldn't get it working. Ended up with this working - `var ndat = $(data).filter("#John_Resig");
     $(".demo-cb-tweets").html(ndat);`

Comment: Now I just need to get it to pull out the names from the text file and assign them depending on which name is hovered over...

Comment: Brilliant cheers - it works! I don't suppose you know how to make it 'dynamic' so it pulls the names out of the text file first, then adds the correct name depending on which name you hover over?

Comment: Just edited and added sample of how to extract the names using jQuery. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! If I was to extract the names on page load in a separate function, how would I access them in the .hovercard success function?

Comment: Pre-loading or loading like it is now in the onHoverIn would work in a similar fashion... with pre-loading you'll be setting those html values somewhere (in a variable, hidden in html, etc) and then doing what you want with that data in the onHoverIn rather than loading the data in on hoverin and extracting the html you need.