# Dynamic hover details with data from text file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the jquery hovercard plugin to pull in text from a text file using ajax when a user hovers over a particular text string - this all works great.

I've added the functionality to search through the content on page load and add a `label` class to any matching names - this works great when the name is defined.

With help on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972038/load-text-from-specific-div-in-text-file-using-ajax); (many thanks @Alex Klock), I have got it so that only one div's text/html is pulled in from the text file on hover - works great when the name is defined.

What I need to do now is pull it all together and make it dynamic, so that all names are pulled out of the text file on page load, the correct `label` class is added to the relevant name/s, and then the correct/corresponding text/html is displayed on hover.

Any help would be massively appreciated : )

*//HTML code*

```
<div id="content">
<p>jQuery by John Resig is a cross-browser JS library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML. It was released in January of 2006 at BarCamp NYC. Used by over 46% of the 10,000 most visited websites, it's the most popular JavaScript library in use today Tim Berners-Lee.</p>                                  
<p>jQuery is free, Tim Berners-Lee open source software, dual-licensed under the MIT License and GNU General Public License, Tim Berners-Lee Version 2.[4] jQuery's syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, and John Resig develop Ajax applications.</p>
</div>
```

*//Jquery code*

```
//based on Highlight words in text with jQuery by (http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/javascript/highlight-words-in-text-with-jquery/)
jQuery.fn.addhover = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<label class=\"" + className + "\" style=\"color:#932121;\">" + match + "</label>";
            });
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {                         

var HTML_FILE_URL = 'helloworld.txt';

$.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function(data) {
    var fileDom = $(data);
    fileDom.filter('.contact').each(function() {
        var savename = $(this).closest(".contact").attr("id");
    });
});

$("#content *").addhover("John Resig", "demo-ajax");

var hoverHTMLDemoAjax = '<div class="demo-cb-tweets"></div>';
$(".demo-ajax").hovercard({
    detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
    width: 350,
    delay: 500,
    cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg',
    onHoverIn: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "text",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".demo-cb-tweets").prepend('<p class="loading-text">Loading latest tweets...</p>');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var people = $(data),
                john = people.filter('#John_Resig');                        
                $(".demo-cb-tweets").empty().append(john);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('.loading-text').remove();
            }
        });
    }
}); 
});
```

*//Helloworld.txt file contents*

```
<div class="contact" id="John_Resig">
<p><strong>John_Resig Testing testing testing!</strong></p>
<p>And on another line of text : )</p>
</div>
<div class="contact" id="Tim_Berners_Lee">
<p><strong>Tim_Berners_Lee Testing testing testing!</strong></p>
<p>And on another line of text : )</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It feels like you're misusing ajax here. You're delaying the initial load of data on the page, but then on one hover, you're requesting everything. I'd suggest using ASP/PHP to limit the response based on needs. You already know what you're hovering over, don't request everything just to filter it. I'll reply soon with a (mildly optimized) solution, that tries to limit loookups. If you want I can offer a PHP file that will greatly optimize this problem. At least how I understand it.

Comment: Double comment! I see you're a css class "demo-cb-tweets", if the helloworld.txt file is populated with tweets, [there are other ways of populating tweets on a page via ajax](https://github.com/kerberoS/jQuery-Tweets)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

For your JavaScript code:

```
jQuery.fn.addhover = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<label class=\"" + className + "\" style=\"color:#932121;\">" + match + "</label>";
            });
        });
    });
};

$(function() {
    var HTML_FILE_URL = 'helloworld.txt';

    $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function(data) {
        var fileDom = $(data);
        fileDom.filter('.contact').each(function() {
            var savename = $(this).closest(".contact").attr("id");
            var hovername = savename.replace(/_/g, ' ');

            $("#content *").addhover(hovername, "demo-ajax");
            var hoverHTMLDemoAjax = '<div class="demo-cb-tweets"></div>';

            $(".demo-ajax").hovercard({
                detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
                width: 350,
                delay: 500,
                cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg',
                onHoverIn: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : HTML_FILE_URL,
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: "text",
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $(".demo-cb-tweets").prepend('<p class="loading-text">Loading latest tweets...</p>');
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            var people = $(data),
                            name = people.filter('#' + savename);
                            $(".demo-cb-tweets").empty().append(name);
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $('.loading-text').remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });


        });
    });


});
```

In your text file, I changed Tim_Berners_Lee to Tim_Berners-Lee. This is to simplify the parsing of the ID in order to easily convert it to its corresponding name:

```
<div class="contact" id="John_Resig">
<p><strong>John_Resig Testing testing testing!</strong></p>
<p>And on another line of text : )</p>
</div>
<div class="contact" id="Tim_Berners-Lee">
<p><strong>Tim_Berners_Lee Testing testing testing!</strong></p>
<p>And on another line of text : )</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a [working model](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/Va5EL/) that at least makes only ajax request. It still feels dirty. I might be able to tweak it even more if you so desire.

```
//based on Highlight words in text with jQuery by (http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/javascript/highlight-words-in-text-with-jquery/)
jQuery.fn.addhover = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<label class=\"" + className + "\" style=\"color:#932121;\" data=\"" + match.replace(' ','_') + "\">" + match + "</label>";
            });
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var HTML_FILE_URL = 'helloworld.txt';
    var cards={};
    var hoverHTMLDemoAjax = '<div class="demo-cb-tweets"></div>';

    $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function (data) {
        cards=$(data);
        cards.each(function() {
            if(!this.id)return;
            $("#content *").addhover(this.id.replace('_',' '), 'demo-ajax');
        });
        $(".demo-ajax").hovercard({
            detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
            width: 350,
            delay: 500,
            cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg',
            onHoverIn: function () {
                $(".demo-cb-tweets").empty().append(cards.filter('#'+$(this).children().eq(0).attr('data')));
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

You need that first ajax request, to get it to work dynamically based on what id's are actually found in your file.

Doing subsequent ajax requests on the same file to get the actual data, feels like really bad design.

I recommend you make two server side files (or one file that handles both requests):

1. **getTypes** => returns the ids that will be used in subsequent ajax request to get the actual data if not already loaded
2. **getData/for/*** => where * is the actual identifier for your data (Ex: Tim_Berners_Lee). Once such a request has been done, it can be cached and re-used.

The approach designed above resembles one of a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) specifically an [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) style web service.

Take note, based on what it is you are trying to achieve, other more optimized solutions may exist. As mentioned in my comment, if you're using this technique to populate with latest tweets. There's no need to bounce that request off of your server. [You can pull it directly from the twitter api](https://github.com/kerberoS/jQuery-Tweets)!